# How do I change the php version using bitnami/linux terminal for my php app

Tags: php, linux, phpmyadmin, lamp, bitnami

So I'm using AWS with bitnami using a linux terminal for my php application. But I need to switch my PHP version from 7.2 to 5.6, and I can't figure out how. I've never used Linux so I'm having trouble, can anyone help?

I've tried this link: https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/

unfortunately none of those commands worked

If anyone is able to help I'd appreciate it very much!

Thank you!

Comment: for the above to work 5.6 has to be installed, is it?

Comment: I know this is probably really stupid, but how do I check and or install 5.6?

Comment: @tim sorry I didn't reply to you directly, but yes how do I check if I have it installed

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami deployments don't support multiple versions of the same component. You will need to install a different stack, in this case the LAMP 5.6 stack (which is not supported anymore) and deploy your PHP code on top of it as you did in the instance you have.

You can download the last version of the Bitnami LAMP solution by running these commands

```
cd /tmp
curl -LO "https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacks/lampstack/5.6.40-1/bitnami-lampstack-5.6.40-1-linux-x64-installer.run
chmod +x ./bitnami-lampstack-5.6.40-1-linux-x64-installer.run
sudo ./bitnami-lampstack-5.6.40-1-linux-x64-installer.run
```

This new installation will use different ports to configure Apache, MySQL, ... if you have another Bitnami installation in the instance. If you want to use the default ports, just stop the default installation.

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
sudo mv /opt/bitnami /opt/bitnami.back
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to install the version of PHP you need so you can run these commands :

- sudo apt install software-properties-common
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install phpx.x (ex : php7.4)
  Then to switch between versions run this :
- update-alternatives --config php
  now you'll get to choose you desired PHP version

Answer (score -1):

1. Backup your current website.
2. Deploy a new Bitnami WordPress instance.
3. Update your DNS records.
4. Install a SSL certificate on new Bitnami WordPress Instance.
5. Modify the `php.ini` file to increase upload size.
6. Import backed up the website on a new Bitnami WordPress website.